# Let user type a number to another number to search in a list

Tags: python

I am trying to make a bus sim. The requirement is for the user to search the passenger range for example 55-67.

Now I made this code but I can only search a specific age and not a range. The user should be able to put in a num to num and then the program should search in the list if it exist.

```
class Buss:
        namn_passagerare = [] # Lagra namnen på passagerare
        passagerare = [] # Lagra ålder på passagerare
        antal_passagerare = 0 # Antal passagerare
        max_passagerare = 3 # Max antal passagerare som kan sitta i bussen



def find_age():


    try: 
        if Buss.antal_passagerare > 0: 
            clear()
            print(Buss.namn_passagerare) # Skriv ut listan "namn_passagerare"
            print(Buss.passagerare) # Skriv ut listan "passagerare"
            leta = float(input('Sök efter ålder: ')) försöka hitta i listan


            hitta = [i for i, age in enumerate(Buss.passagerare) if age == leta] 
            if hitta:
                print('Passagerare med ålder {0} hittades på position: {1}'.format(leta, ', '.join(map(str, hitta))))
else:
print('Inga passagerare med åldern {0} hittades.'.format(leta))
input('Tryck Enter för att gå vidare')
else:
clear()
```

Comment: Can you indent your code more clearly? Thanks!

Comment: `hitta = [i for i, age in enumerate(Buss.passagerare) if startålder <= age <= slutålder] ` you will have to prompt for a start and end age not a find age of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

def find_age():

```
try: # Försök
    if Buss.antal_passagerare > 0:
        clear()
        print("Passagerarnas åldrar:")
        print(Buss.passagerare)  # Print out the ages of the passengers

        startalder = float(input('Ålder 1: '))
        slutalder = float(input('Ålder 2: '))

        hitta = [i for i, age in enumerate(Buss.passagerare) if startalder <= age <= slutalder]
        if hitta:
            found_ages = [Buss.passagerare[i] for i in hitta]
            print('Passagerare med ålder {0} hittades på position: {1}'.format(', '.join(map(str, found_ages)), ', '.join(map(str, hitta))))
        else:
            print('Inga passagerare med åldern mellan {0} och {1} hittades.'.format(startalder, slutalder))
        input('Tryck Enter för att gå vidare')
    else:
        clear()
        print('Inga passagerare att söka bland.')
        input('Tryck Enter för att gå vidare')
except ValueError:
    clear()
    print('Felaktig inmatning. Försök igen.')
    input('Tryck Enter för att gå tillbaka till menyn')
```